# Numpy log on division with 0 in numerator gives "divide by zero" warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have 120,000 X 120,000 numpy array called NUMERATOR of the format:

```
STEP1: NUMERATOR =

[[8.85191777e-12 0.00000000e+00 6.62258993e-12 ... 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
:
[0.00000000e+00 1.22870643e-11 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]
```

I have another (120,000,) numpy array called DENOMINATOR.

```
STEP2 DENOMINATOR =
[8.85191777e-12 0.00000000e+00 6.62258993e-12 ... 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]

To avoid a "divide by zero" error, I updated DENOMINATOR array as
DENOMINATOR = DENOMINATOR + 0.00000000000001
```

Now we find a NEW_DENOMINATOR as follows:

```
STEP3:

NEW_DENOMINATOR = np.multiply.outer(DENOMINATOR, DENOMINATOR)
which results in  a 120,000 X 120,000 matrix as follows:

[[1.78266171e-13 5.62788054e-13 5.75945750e-13 ... 6.33114532e-18
 2.82924941e-18 4.22215788e-21]
:
[5.62788054e-13 1.77672741e-12 1.81826639e-12 ... 1.99874880e-17
 8.93196817e-18 1.33293939e-20]]
```

The computation I wanted to perform is:
np.log2(NUMERATOR/NEW_DENOMINATOR),
however I still recieve the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2
output=np.log2(NUMERATOR/NEW_DENOMINATOR)

and the output looks like:
[[5.63388519       -inf 3.5233907  ...       -inf       -inf       -inf]
[      -inf 2.78984599       -inf ...       -inf       -inf       -inf]
:
[5.63388519       -inf 3.5233907  ...       -inf       -inf       -inf]
[      -inf 2.78984599       -inf ...       -inf       -inf       -inf]

]
```

What is python showing this warning? The results are containing inf which means a division by zero was performed. Why is this happening even tho the denominator doesn't contain a 0?

Comment: Can I ask why you are add a small number to your denominator instead of accepting `x/0 == np.nan`? Is it critical to your application?

Comment: Yes, whenever the num!=0 I wanted real values to which I can apply np.log2 to.

Comment: @Guimoute also I assumed the zero in the denominator was giving the warning when i performed log2 on them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "divide by zero" warning is slightly confusing, as you are (most likely) not dividing by zero in `NUMERATOR/NEW_DENOMINATOR`. Instead, you are trying to calculate the `log2` of zero values. Internally, `numpy` most likely performs a division by the input of `log2`, giving you this warning.

Remember that the logarithm of zero is not defined; the limit of the logarithm of zero approaching from the positive side is −∞. If you take a closer look at your output, you see that this is also the value stored in your output, not positive infinity. See the figure below, of `log2(x)` as function of `x` ([source: Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Log_(2).svg))

[image: log2(x) as function of x]

Comment: Right.  As further evidence, notice that the results are not actually `inf`, but `-inf`.  That's exactly what you get from `np.log2(0)`.

Comment: Thank you both for the pointers, I will perform the division before computing log2

Comment: @TheLastCoder This will not solve your problem. The issue is not in the division, but in the fact that you are computing log2 of zero. You need to ensure that there are no zeros in both your numerator (because 0/x = 0, and log2(0) = −∞ in Python) and your denominator (because x/0 = ∞, and log2(∞) = ∞ in Python) if you want this behaviour to disappear. If calculating log2(0) is correct for your application, you can simply ignore the warning.